# Understanding transaction isolation during delete

Tags: postgresql, transactions

Let's say I have a table that stores sales for a shoe store. Now, let's say, in the same db transaction, I delete all of the sales for a date (2021-09-08) and then refill the sales for that day (so a delete and insert in the same transaction).  If a separate select transaction, that selects sales on 2021-09-08, were to run at the same time as the delete/insert transaction, could that select transaction potential come back with 0 results. That is, can the select run before the delete but before the insert.

I know that a delete does not lock the whole table in postgres (at least, I think that is correct). But maybe the transaction runs the delete/insert in such a way that the table never looks empty to a separate select transaction?  I don't really understand how the transaction works. Is it deleting/inserting in some temporary memory, that is then committed to the actual table data (I don't think that is correct).

Our app frequently blows out data for certain dates (delete/insert), I am wondering if a the table could every look empty, on a specific date, to a client that is running a select.  I think the answers is no...but I realize I don't really know this. I kn

Comment: Rather then repeat the docs I will point you at [Transaction Isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html). Short version is the `SELECT` will see the data in the table before the `DELETE/INSERT` transaction started, assuming default isolation level.

Answer (score 2):

While a transaction is in progress, other transactions cannot see its modifications. So if you delete and insert data in the same transaction, concurrent queries can either see the status before the transaction started (the old data) or the status after commit (the new data). Nobody outside the modifying transaction itself will ever see an empty table.

Answer (score 0):

The foundation for what you're asking about is [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID), specifically [Isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)) and [Atomicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)).  As @adrian-klaver notes, Postgres has good documentation of it's [Transaction Isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html).

But generally speaking, what happens in a transaction will be totally and completely invisible to other users before it is committed ([Isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems))), and after it is committed the entire set of changes will be immediately visible to all other users ([Atomicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems))). It's all or nothing, and it's not possible for another user of the database to view an intermediate state of what's happening within a transaction (and if the transaction is rolled back, it will be *almost* impossible for any other user to tell).